# If Rust is not garbage collected, how is memory cleaned / released?

Tags: rust

I have seen a build function called **drop(T)** in rust, basically, it moves the given variable.

let's say if we have code as follow:

```
struct Obj {
    a: i32,
}

impl Drop for Obj {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("> Dropping {}", self.a);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = &Obj { a: 5 };

    m = &Obj { a: 6 };
    m = &Obj { a: 7 };
    m = &Obj { a: 8 };

    let t = thread::spawn(|| {
        for i in 0..5 {
            println!("Counting {}", i);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs_f32(1.0));
        }
    });
    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

The Result is :

```
> Dropping 6
> Dropping 7
> Dropping 8
Counting 0
Counting 1
Counting 2
Counting 3
Counting 4
> Dropping 5
```

As the result shows the 6 to 8 has been collected just after resignments, the origin 5 is lasting until the end of main. why the 5 is not collected in the first place?

Comment: Everything owned in the scope is droped ("cleaned") when its scope ends.

Comment: @Netwave in the case of code, can I clean the Obj{5} by hand before the end of main

Comment: @Netwave that's not going to compile, you can't move out of a rerference.

Comment: @EnXie you can if you keep it named (as is, it's an anonymous temporary) and drop all its references beforehand, but that's not going to do anything useful since it doesn't implement `Drop`.

Comment: @Masklinn, yeah, I was actually building the proper answer.

Comment: @Masklinn if I keep changing the pointer 'm' to some other new &Obj , as long as the program running. Are there will be a lot of older Objs in memory, if so how long it will last ?

Comment: @EnXie depends on the decision of the optimiser. Semantically until the end of the stackframe, but practically the stack allocator could decide to reuse older and now-dead locations. Now sure whether or how much llvm bothers with that.

Comment: The duplicate and existing answers don't really explain the drop behavior here. Essentially `m = &...;` doesn't do what you want, it assigns a reference to `m` but the `...` is immediately dropped. You'll see the compiler yield an error if you actually tried to use `m`. The `let m = &...;` is actually slightly different and persists the `...` until the end of the scope. Perhaps, OP, you should ask a fresh question with that as the focus if you're interested in more details.

Answer (score 3):

I think compiler will insert code like this

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut _1 = Obj { a: 5 };
    let mut m = &_1;
    let mut _2 = Obj { a: 6 };
    m = &_2;

    drop(_1);
    drop(_2);
}
```

so origin `Obj` will drop when exit `main` scope

Comment: I have tried the Drop Traits.. something interesting happened, do you know how it works?

Comment: I don’t know how it works. I just remember reading a book before, introducing direct reference, the compiler will create a temporary variable after compilation, and then the temporary variable is manipulated by the compiler. But I don’t know what the compiler will do with it

Answer (score 1):

Everything owned in the scope is droped ("cleaned") after the scope ends.
In this case, if you want to manually drop it, you can, but need to make everything explicit to the compiler:

```rust
struct Obj {
    a: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let obj_a = Obj { a: 5 }; // get an owned object
    let mut a = &obj_a; // use a reference to the object
    a = &Obj { a: 6 }; // change to another object reference
    drop(obj_a); // drop the original OWNED object manually
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4fa0f0d556fe7866753984c147276a45)

> What happens to the original Obj?

In your case you lose access to the owned version of the object, so it is just dropped at the end of the scope. But you can always have it in a variable that you can manually drop at any point you need.

> if Rust has no GC, how to clean it by manual?

Use `drop` over **owned** data.

On the updated example:

> why the 5 is not collected in the first place?

The compiler is smart enough to sometimes foresee that you are not really using anything there. Mi interpretation is that it is trying to optimise the code.

Check what happens if you manually drop the `5` obj.

```rust
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;


struct Obj {
    a: i32,
}

impl Drop for Obj {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("> Dropping {}", self.a);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let obj = Obj { a: 5 };
    let mut m = &obj;

    m = &Obj { a: 6 };
    drop(obj);
    m = &Obj { a: 7 };
    m = &Obj { a: 8 };

    let t = thread::spawn(|| {
        for i in 0..5 {
            println!("Counting {}", i);
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs_f32(1.0));
        }
    });
    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c9f3e4cdd392a38dc89ec2537fe5141)

Comment: I have updated my question, and Implement a Drop Traint  something interesting happened.

Comment: @EnXie, I expanded the answer with your new example. But please do not keep updating the question, it is usually better to open a newly related question instead :)

Comment: Got it. I will do it next time. many thx

Answer (score 0):

Rust ownership takes care of object lifetime. It is freed when out of the scope, unless `moved` meaning the responsibility to free it passed down to another scope.

Try adding [Drop Traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/drop.html) to your object to see when it is freed.

Further reading,

- [Smart Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)
- [Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html)
- [ARC](https://medium.com/@DylanKerler1/how-arc-works-in-rust-b06192acd0a6)

Comment: I have tried the Drop Traits.. something interesting happened, I have updated my question.